Inner Header-Based Actions in OVS
OVS switch in mininet receives IPsec packets in AH Tunnel Mode (IP-in-IP encapsulation). I want to apply actions based on the inner IP packet headers, which exist in the payload of the outer IP and are not encrypted due to the use of AH. Is it possible to avoid sending each packet to the controller (ryu) by installing a rule that matches packets based on the inner packet headers?
